# how to access an object before inserting in a BST

Tags: c++, class, binary-search-tree

First, I would like to apologise if I am not clear enough. here is my issue:

I am asked to create a BST with node object dollar. I was able to create my root and I would like to insert a new node. I know that I have to compare my objects using my overloading operator but I am confused with how to bring in those object. It is clear that the first object will be the one within the tree ( the root will be the first to consider if any).

1. I have to compare the dollar object c with the objects already in my tree but I cannot figure out how to access those ones in my insert function. Could you please help me?
2. I would like to return a node at the end of my insert function but I have an error. What should I do? thank you

   ```
    class Dollar
    {
    protected:
        int wholePart;
        int fractionalPart;
        std::string currencyName;
    public:
        void setwholePart(int w){
            wholePart = w;
        }
        int getwholePart(){
            return wholePart;
        }
        void setfractionalPart(int f){
            fractionalPart = f;
        }
        int getfractionalPart(){
            return fractionalPart;
        }
        void setcurrencyName(std::string c){
            currencyName = c;
        }
        std::string getcurrencyName(){
            return currencyName;
        }
        Dollar();//Constructor
        Dollar(int w, int f, std::string c);
        ~Dollar();//Destructor
        Dollar operator +(Dollar &other);//overlaoding operator to declare add function
        Dollar operator -(Dollar&other);//overlaoding operator to declare withdraw function
        bool operator==(Dollar &other);//overlaoding operator to declare equality function
        Dollar operator >(Dollar&other);//overlaoding operator to declare comparison function
        void conversionMethod(int w, int f, std::string c);
    };

    Dollar::Dollar() //Initializing the variables of Dollar class
    {
        wholePart=0;
        fractionalPart=0;
        currencyName="";
    }

    Dollar::Dollar(int w,int f,std::string c) //Function definition

    {
        wholePart=w;
        fractionalPart=f;
        currencyName=c;
    }

    Dollar::~Dollar() //Destructor definition
    {
        std::cout << "\n Dollar Object is being destroyed"<< std::endl;
    }

    int total=0,total1=0;


    Dollar Dollar::operator+(Dollar &other)

    {

        Dollar result; //Object creation so it can read the result of the add operation

        total = (wholePart + other.wholePart)*100+ fractionalPart + other.fractionalPart; //Performing the add after conversion in cents

            //Breaking calculated value down between whole and fractional Parts
        result.wholePart=total/100;
        result.fractionalPart=total % 100;
        result.currencyName = currencyName;


        return result;
    }

        //Defining > operator
    Dollar Dollar:: operator >(Dollar&other)
    {
        Dollar result;
        if(wholePart>other.wholePart)
            {
            return *this;
            }
        else if(wholePart<other.wholePart)
            {
            return result;
            }
        else if(wholePart==other.wholePart)
            {
            if(fractionalPart>other.fractionalPart)
                return *this;
            }
        return result;
    }


    struct Node {
        Dollar data;
        Node* par;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
            //Node() : elt(), par(NULL), left(NULL), right(NULL) { } // constructor
    };

    Node *create (class Dollar, int x, int y, std::string currency){
        Dollar obj;
        Node *temp= new Node();
    //    temp->data.setwholePart(obj.getwholePart());
    //    temp->data.setfractionalPart(obj.getfractionalPart());
    //    temp->right=temp->left=NULL;

        temp->data.setwholePart(x);//reading the user entry into wholepart
            temp->data.setfractionalPart(y);//reading the user entry into wholepart
            temp->data.setcurrencyName("USD");//reading the user entry into wholepart
    //    obj.setfractionalPart(y);//reading the user entry into fractional part
    //    obj.setcurrencyName("USD");//assigning the currency name
        return temp;
    }

    Node Insert(Node * node, Dollar c)

    {




        if(node == NULL)
            {
            node = new Node;
            node->data.setwholePart(c.getwholePart());
            node->data.setfractionalPart(c.getfractionalPart());
            node->left = NULL;
            node->right = NULL;
            node->par = NULL;
            }
            // If the given key is greater than
            // node's key then go to right subtree
        else if(node->data > node)
            {
            node->right = Insert(node->right,c);
            node->right->par = node;
            }
            // If the given key is smaller than
            // node's key then go to left subtree
        else
            {
            node->left = Insert(node->left, key);
            node->left->par = node;
            }
        return Node;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dollar` class has *value semantics*. It's slightly fancier than an `int` or a `std::string`, but the idea is similar. This makes it easy to use the class.

Each `Node` *contains* a `Dollar` value. This class is a bit stranger, though. It doesn't have a real constructor, but you did write a `Node* create` function instead. The weirdness of that function continues; it has an *unnamed* first argument of type `Dollar`. Presumably you wanted to name this argument `obj`, but now `create` has a second `Dollar` object. That second object is unrelated to the unnamed argument, and has a default value.

Fix:

```
Node::Node (Dollar obj) :
 data { obj }, par {nullptr}, left{nullptr}, right{nullptr}
{
}
```

Since it's a simple constructor, you can just use the initializer list to provide intializers for all four `Node` members.

Comment: thank you for the help. My issue is that my overloading operator has Dollar obj parameter. How to compare the dollar objects with the ones already in the node then? it may seem pretty clear to you but it is not to me because I am learning programming.